# How to prevent a div break to the next line

Tags: html, css

i have a div with two divs inside with the following structure.

[image: Blocks]

However when the second div has more content it looks like this.

[image: second block]

What can i do in order to get something like this?

[image: block wrap]

The content of the second div has just text and the text continues underneath the first div.

Comment: It’s not possible with a 2 div elements. Divs are boxes. The first element should be a div but the text on the right should be a paragraph or a collection of paragraphs.

Comment: Float your first div to the left. Too vague? Post your HTML and CSS so that we can see what you're working with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate using float, but it would handle what you are after.

```css
.floater {
  background-color: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  width: 40%;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div class="floater">Morbi posuere elementum finibus. Donec tincidunt, arcu ac egestas ornare, nulla nulla ullamcorper arcu, sit amet consequat nunc quam ac justo. Nulla vestibulum cursus erat, vel aliquam lorem rhoncus vel. Praesent non dolor ut ligula scelerisque varius. Maecenas eu enim in enim dignissim suscipit. Duis aliquet scelerisque imperdiet. Cras ac convallis arcu, vel semper elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque non mauris sed nibh egestas semper eget in odio. Suspendisse ornare ut enim at consequat. In fermentum libero augue, vitae auctor sem pellentesque ut. Nulla a erat porttitor, consequat neque eget, aliquet lectus. Sed hendrerit et lorem ut tempus. Donec placerat ipsum sit amet dui ullamcorper, sed semper quam dictum. Aliquam nunc magna, gravida et sagittis id, pretium et nisl. Cras mollis felis diam, non pellentesque orci cursus et. Quisque vestibulum tincidunt magna sit amet sodales. Aliquam aliquam nibh dolor, sed sodales odio convallis in. Cras dapibus aliquet finibus. Vivamus eu leo mattis, suscipit ex vitae, aliquet dolor.

Ut convallis, urna aliquet lobortis facilisis, sem justo varius ipsum, eu tincidunt augue purus varius libero. Sed mauris justo, ornare et fringilla a, tristique at sapien. Mauris bibendum iaculis risus, tincidunt euismod quam placerat volutpat. Maecenas interdum ornare nisl nec convallis. Pellentesque elit dui, viverra ac ipsum non, tempor interdum tortor. Aenean in pellentesque justo. Aenean sit amet rutrum lectus. Donec commodo fermentum nunc, et tempus enim iaculis vitae. Praesent venenatis vulputate scelerisque.

Vivamus auctor ex nec elit imperdiet, eget hendrerit lacus lacinia. Suspendisse consectetur quis arcu mollis aliquam. Maecenas condimentum arcu risus, eget gravida justo ultricies in. Maecenas pretium sem ante, ut tempor velit imperdiet non. Mauris cursus tortor eget ultricies aliquam. Vivamus lacinia efficitur quam et sollicitudin. Morbi pretium in eros nec egestas. Sed ut libero nec mi sollicitudin rhoncus ut a purus. Cras vitae iaculis purus. Nullam at rhoncus enim. Nunc sed vestibulum elit. Praesent volutpat neque nec congue egestas. Vestibulum sit amet porttitor massa, sit amet varius purus. Aliquam id maximus lorem.

Suspendisse sed nunc convallis, bibendum arcu a, fermentum nulla. Quisque eget lorem at dui tempus sodales nec ut arcu. Pellentesque sodales nunc ac massa tincidunt, a pretium purus condimentum. Aenean vitae bibendum mi. In interdum, lorem ac rhoncus ullamcorper, ligula nisl elementum turpis, ut ultricies massa sem eget libero. Etiam fermentum blandit nisl et volutpat. Sed molestie ante vitae leo pharetra volutpat. In at felis sem. Praesent eu nunc eu purus posuere tempus in ac est. Nullam quis arcu velit. Integer nec nulla sit amet velit cursus semper. Ut turpis arcu, fermentum a nisi non, feugiat molestie odio. Morbi et felis pulvinar, blandit nisl non, pellentesque tellus.

Praesent ac risus at turpis dignissim eleifend. Cras non magna facilisis nulla vulputate bibendum id et augue. Integer tempor eleifend suscipit. Mauris dolor arcu, consectetur in congue at, fringilla cursus nisi. Pellentesque vestibulum congue odio sed pretium. Proin ante justo, volutpat vitae pharetra in, porta non turpis. Morbi ut risus molestie, sagittis erat ut, facilisis mauris. Aenean ultrices sem non elit mollis, eu volutpat metus posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque odio mi, auctor non turpis at, faucibus dapibus massa. Curabitur dapibus turpis malesuada vehicula dignissim. Nunc non mollis justo. In posuere faucibus sodales. Praesent accumsan leo at egestas sollicitudin.</div>
```

Comment: using inline-block with float is useless

Comment: You need either black or inline-block to use margins. And I never use block when I don't have something go all the way from left to right.

Comment: you don't need to specify display at all (inline-block or block) when using float the element will a block element by default so the display is useless

Comment: After looking into to it, I discovered that setting `float` causes the `display` to be set to `block`. I did not know that before. But, like I said. I hate float.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set a **width** (either fixed or max-width) and a **left float** on your first div. Here's a ***very*** rudimentary example:

```html
<div style="background-color: blue; padding: 10px;">
<div style="background-color: blue; color: white; float: left; margin-right: 20px; padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px; width: 50%;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet quam porta, porttitor leo sed.
</div>
<div style="background-color: red; color: white; padding: 10px; ">
    Quisque erat mi, pretium ut nibh ut, vulputate sollicitudin leo. Quisque condimentum leo tortor, et vulputate justo aliquet convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis aliquam ligula velit, vulputate aliquam elit tincidunt at. Maecenas at turpis pretium, convallis lacus quis, efficitur ipsum. Quisque ullamcorper mauris et tortor laoreet rutrum. Sed tincidunt metus quis maximus interdum. Phasellus at sodales arcu, nec bibendum neque. Donec id posuere enim, pellentesque elementum augue. Donec venenatis libero sapien, a tempor dolor tristique ac.
</div>
</div>
```

Check out the w3schools entry here for a full reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the downvote? I know that the div itself isn't wrapped around the other one, but the content within the 2nd div can be. Then, at that point, you can simulate that exact effect by specifying additional padding/margins.

Comment: I realize in my infinite wisdom, I forgot to include the most obvious and essential part of the whole thing...the left float...I've updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

you can try floating it i.e

```
float: left;
```

but you should know that each div acts like a block, and each block cant overlap the other, except one is inside the other, so put ine small div inside the big div, the float the small div

Answer (score -3):

Not really possible unless its text wrapping around a div/img. You can't have a div wrap around another div.

You could create a shape like this: (no ie support)
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/